# I need to load script on click event

Tags: jquery

Hi! I need to load my script on click event... I have a button. I want to call my google script on that button click.

```
     $("#MSC_AddNewAddress").click(function(){

           ShippingAddressID=-1;
           MSC_ShowAddShipping();
           MSC_Script();
    });

      function MSC_Script(){
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true';
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          document.body.parentNode.appendChild(script);

}
```

Comment: And where is your issue? Explain it better. BTW, why not including google maps by default, instead of reincluding it on each click?

Comment: post your HTML, and if you are using ASP mention that

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 0):

You have the [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for this :

```
$("#MSC_AddNewAddress").click(function(){
    $.getScript( "script.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        // success
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it does... It wouldn't be implemented in jQuery otherwise. Maybe your problem is somewhere else. Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: i got a error  

 TypeError: google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor
http://www.baloobalive.com/Home.aspx
Line 704

Comment: Maybe you are trying to use the google maps API before actually loading it. You have to execute your custom code inside the callback function, where I wrote the `// success` comment

Answer (score 0):

Consider including

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` snippet in your web page.

And then Something like (a jquery function will work)
[jQuery.getScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript#urlcallback)

```
$("#MSC_AddNewAddress").click(function(){
  $.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ));
});
```

OR by pure javascript

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true';
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.body.parentNode.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>
```

HTML for button

```
<button id="MSC_AddNewAddress" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

Comment: I got an error in console

TypeError: google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor
http://www.baloobalive.com/Home.aspx
Line 704

Comment: This is something other issue not related to the question you put here, in order to solve the same try reading https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial